# Mongodb intersection with time range

Tags: mongodb, redis, database

In MongodB we found the method for intersection, but we also would like to implement date range exclusion. Let me explain.

We have got the daily rota for each support team. Each support team can be booked every 15 minutes for 5-25 minutes (approx). In each team there are 2-10 people. We need to show the next available time slot for the specified team.

For example:

Initial free slots on Monday (everyone in the team is availabe)

```
08:00, 08:15, 08:30, 08:45, 09:00...
```

First ticket gets assigned to 1st person(out of 2), and this ticket is scheduled for lets say `08:15`, and it will take `35 minutes` to complete. So the free slots will look exactly the same:

```
08:00, 08:15, 08:30, 08:45, 09:00...
    (08:15-08:50 1/2 busy)
```

Second ticket arrives and is scheduled for `08:30` and will take one hour to complete. So the free slots should look like this:

```
08:00, 08:15,09:00...
(08:15-08:50 1st of 2 busy)
(08:30-09:30 2nd of 2 busy)
```

We are fully aware that now we ca nallow the ticket for `08:15` to be available for maximum of 15 minutes as the second person will start doing its next job at `08:30` but first we'd like to focus on excluding times and finding proper intersections base don the scheduled tickets.

We also though about using redis instead of MongoDB, but that's just another idea.

Comment: removed the `mysql` tag. unrelated to anything mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

you can use redis' sets for this use case:

If the time slots are always in multiples of 15 minutes you can do like this:

1) Have a universal set containing all the time slots. Here multiples of 15.

```
sadd universal 08:00 08:15 08:30 08:45 09:00 ...
```

2) For each member in the team have a separate set for the slots booked for them. For member1 **08:15-08:50** you have to make him engaged till **09:00**.

```
sadd member_1 08:15 08:30 08:45 09:00
```

3) Similarly do for other members also. member2 **08:30-09:30**

```
sadd member_2 08:30 08:45 09:00 09:30
```

4) Now for each member you can get the free slots using

```
sdiff universal member_1
```

5) For the overall slots free. You have to do two operations.

```
result = sinter member_1 member_2 ...
sdiff universal result
```

intersecting all the member's set will give the time slots where all the users are busy. So you can't allot those slots.

Doing a subtract (diff) operation with the universal set will give you the overall slots that is free to be occupied.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can we have a chat via email please?